# Почему некорректно работает свойство HtmUrl?

Tags: html, .net, asp.net, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Я использую библиотеку DinkToPdf, которая по сути является врапером wkhtmltopdf для.NET. Мне нужно использовать кастомный html хедер для страничек и я использую свойство HtmUrl в которое передаётся путь файла из которого этот самый html и должен браться. Вот только по какой-то причине оно не работает корректно, ломаясь, то отображает просто текст который содержится в разметке и иногда  бонусом отображает то, что находится в тексте передаваемого хедера, а иногда и просто рендерится нормально, но без намёка на наличие чего-то сверху вообще.
Я думал изначально что может дело в стилях или html, так как при ошибке в одном из двух демонстрируется просто текст который содержится в передаваемой коде. Однако как выяснилось, ошибка возникает даже тогда когда стили или разметка в полном порядке. Даже если оставить файл с html хедера пустым, код ломается и снова таки демонстрируется просто текст...
Может быть кто-то сталкивался с этим, если да, то как решить и почему вообще может возникать?

```
    
    StringBuilder htmlCode = new StringBuilder("Adds image at the start of the pdf file");
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\assets\\header.html");
    StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder(withNewCell ? CreateTable(gridView, true) : CreateTable(gridView));
    htmlCode.Append(table.ToString());
    var test = htmlCode.ToString();
    var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
    {
        GlobalSettings = {
                ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                Orientation = DinkToPdf.Orientation.Landscape,
                PaperSize = PaperKind.A4Plus,
            },
        Objects = {
                new ObjectSettings() {
                    PagesCount = true,
                    HtmlContent = test,
                    WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8", PrintMediaType = true, },
                    //Works normaly only when there is text property or is empty
                    HeaderSettings = { HtmUrl= path, Spacing = 0}
                }
            }
    };
    byte[] pdf = _converter.Convert(doc);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```